# Forward TCP traffic through computer

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have a computer (A) that makes a request to a webservice. It is not connected by a wire to the router but it is on the same LAN than another computer (B) that has 2 network interfaces (one to the lan 172.25.0.0/23 (enp27s0) and the other connected to a Router 192.168.255.0/24 (enp29s0)).

I am able to connect a receive a response if I make the request from the computer B (I have added a route in computer B) but not if I make the request from computer A.

I have this configuration:

1. Computer A:

`default via 172.25.0.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100 
172.25.0.0/23 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.1.24 metric 100 
217.xxx.yyy.0/24 via 172.25.1.14 dev ens192`

2. Computer B:

`default via 172.25.0.1 dev enp27s0 proto static metric 100 
default via 192.168.255.2 dev enp29s0 proto static metric 101 
172.25.0.0/23 dev enp27s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.1.14 metric 100 
192.168.255.0/24 dev enp29s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.255.14 metric 100 
217.xxx.yyy.0/24 via 192.168.255.2 dev enp29s0 proto static metric 99`

On computer B, I have tried to insert this iptables config and the computer has ipv4 forwarding enabled:

`iptables -A FORWARD -i enp27s0 -o enp29s0 -p tcp --syn --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp27s0 -o enp29s0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp29s0 -o enp27s0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp27s0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 217.124.156.199
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp29s0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -d 172.25.1.24 -j SNAT --to-source 172.25.1.14
root@joaquin2:~# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i enp27s0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.25.1.14:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.25.1.14 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 172.25.1.14 -o enp27s0 -j MASQUERADE`

If I execute a traceroute command in computer A, this is the result got:

`traceroute webservice.example.com
traceroute to webservice.example.com (217.xxx.yyy.199), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.25.1.14 (172.25.1.14)  0.309 ms  0.231 ms  0.200 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *`

but I am not able to receive a response. It seems that the request stops on computer B.

To clarify, I attach a picture:

**Detailed diagram**

[image: Detailed diagram]

On both computers, I have Debian 9 Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup should almost work, except:

- Only half of your firewall rules apply to your situation, the other half are never reached,
- What you did is setup a kind of reverse proxy from port 8080 of machine B to the specific web service. If you open the webservice in a browser it should probably work, but ping and traceroute certainly will not, since the SNAT rules don't cover the ICMP protocol.
- You have two default routes on host B. This should probably be corrected. If you used `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure networking, you should delete the `gateway` option of interface `enp27s0`.

I would propose a simpler configuration, easier to grasp. Basically you want to configure computer B as gateway, so flush the firewall chains and start again:

```
iptables -t filter -F; iptables -t nat -F
```

You need to:

- Activate routing on machine B (it is probably active by default):

  ```
  sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- Allow all traffic through the machine and setup source NAT on the `enp29s0` interface:

  ```
  iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp29s0 -s 172.25.0.0/23 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.255.14
  ```
- You can check the correctness of the firewall configuration with:

  ```
  iptables -nvL
  iptables -t nat -nvL
  ```

  and you'll an increase in the number of packets matched, for every packet you send
  from host A.

To make this permanent between reboots, add:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and:

```
post-up /usr/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables.conf
pre-down /usr/sbin/iptables-save -f /etc/iptables.conf
```

to the `enp29s0` interface configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

**PS**: off course the simplest configuration of all is to add a static route on your router for network `172.25.0.0/23` with next hop `192.168.255.14`, then the SNAT is not necessary. However not all so called  “routers” can do it.